# Angular next and prev navigation math logic

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is probably a piece of cake for you math gurus. The prevSlide goes back fine 3-2-1-3-2... etc. Regardless of the point of entry. But the nexSlide starts out 1-2-3 and then it just 2-3-2-3...I'm sure it's my math

```
$scope.currentIndex = 0;
$scope.setCurrentSlideIndex = function (index) {
    $scope.currentIndex = index;
};
$scope.isCurrentSlideIndex = function (index) {
    return $scope.currentIndex === index;
};
$scope.prevSlide = function () {
    $scope.currentIndex = ($scope.currentIndex > 0) ? --$scope.currentIndex : $scope.slides.length - 1;
};
$scope.nextSlide = function () {
    $scope.currentIndex = ($scope.currentIndex < $scope.slides.length -1) ? ++$scope.currentIndex : 1;
};
```

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.nextSlide = function () {
    $scope.currentIndex = ($scope.currentIndex < $scope.slides.length -1) ? ++$scope.currentIndex : 0;
};
```

You just need to change the `1` to a `0` at the end of this line. index `1` as you have it now is actually the 2nd slide.

```
Slide #: 1 -- 2 -- 3
Index #: 0 -- 1 -- 2
```

Comment: Golden! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to change to match your context but the logic in the functions `previous()` and `next()` below might help.

```
var numSlides = 3;

function previous(current){
  current--;
  return current >= 0 ? current : numSlides;
}

function next(current){
  current++;
  return current <= numSlides ? current : 0;
}
```

Comment: You can always use the modulo (%) operator for any clock arithmetic. `return (++current) % numSlides`

Comment: This is a good solution for pure javascript, but the other answer helped me better since it's still angular and didn't require a lot to make it work. Besides, I can't hardcode the amount of slides. It must remain dynamic i case the user adds more than 3 slides to the component. But I did +1 your answer. Thanks!